# Make td element clickable using href

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make certain elements of a table clickable using the href tag. Currently I can only make the text inside the td elements clickable, but I want the whole element to be clickable.

The version below works fine:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="link">Click</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

add  onclick on your td :

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="location.replace('https://www.sociat.com')">Click</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: don't forget to add cursor:pointer on your css file

Comment: Thanks. Can I also use target=_blank using this method?

Comment: No for that use : onclick="window.open('https://www.sociat.com ', '_blank')"

Comment: Perfect, works great.
But why exactly does an a element not work in this case?

Comment: a element work fine inside a td  maybe you have space in there, try making padding to 0 (zero) and your td will now work fine

Comment: Yes ofc, but the a element worked fine on the background of a div, why doesn't it on the td background? ^^ 

Without the padding the "buttons" would look pretty ugly, too.